# Win7 installation on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my machine. I also installed Virtualbox so that I can run windows 7.

I set my virtual box with 4 GB RAM and 25 GB virtual HDD and after I press Start, it doesnt boot from the windows dvd in the optical drive, but instead i get this error:

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine win7.

```
VT-x features locked or unavailable in MSR. (VERR_VMX_MSR_LOCKED_OR_DISABLED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb}
```

Do you have any idea what is it and how I could overcome this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You must enable hardware virtualization in BIOS

[Source](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=8669)

Answer (score 4):

All virtualization solutions nowadays attempt to use **hardware assisted** virtualization, instead of **software emulation solutions** (binary translation). One of those hardware virtualization technologies is **Intel's virtualization technology**(VT-x). Although AMD supports its own virtualization technology (AMD-V), the basic processor virtualization extensions are named after Intel's solution. I would not like to go any further on virtualization theory and such, if you would like to read, this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization) is highly informational.

## How to enable VT-x

There are two configurations you should perform if you would like to enable hardware assisted virtualization. Those are:

- [First of all, make sure that you have enabled Virtualization extensions in your hardware](https://www.google.gr/search?q=how%20to%20enable%20virtualization%20in%20bios&sugexp=chrome,mod=10&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).
- **After you have done so, Enable vt-x in the virtual machine configurations**. To do so: Right click on a virtual machine in the Virtual Box user interface -> Settings -> System -> Acceleration -> Enable Vt-x/AMD-v

[image]